# Fire event in extension on keyboard shortcut

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, macros

My friend challenged me to figure out a way to control YouTube (in Chrome) from the computer desktop (Or a program different from Chrome). Basically the idea here is to fire an event where I can handle what to do with certain hotkey combos. Chrome [has an api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands) (`chrome.commands`) that allows for this, but the user must be in chrome for it to fire the event (which makes sense). I would like to discuss any possible alternatives.

I know extensions can have file access to the computer (using `chrome.fileSystem` [api](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem)), so I was thinking of having a folder somewhere that had text file(s) that would be written to by a script running on the user's computer. The script could also potentially just be a macro fired by Windows on a certain key stroke.

Is this a practical approach, or are there easier ways to accomplish this? It just seems like there's a lot of "moving" parts needed to make this work.

EDIT: Main goal here is to get skip and pause/play keys (that some keyboards have) to work with chrome. using Ctrl+Shift+[0-9] works with `chrome.commands`, but anyone have other suggestions to get those other keys to work?

Comment: `but the user must be in chrome` - nope, simply declare a [global scope](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands#scope).

Comment: *Generically* working outside of Chrome is a job for an OS-level tool or scripting language, which allows you to define hotkeys at the OS-level or auto-translate one hotkey combo/mouse-click combo into another (both maybe in conjunction with a Chrome extension). Look for such tools, or write your own script in one of multiple scripting languages. On Windows, both [tag:autohotkey] and [tag:autoit] would work for the OS level integration. If you want something more versatile, then you can interface with Chrome using [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome.commands` has a very limited set of shortcuts that work *globally*:

> By default, Commands are scoped to the Chrome browser, which means that while the browser does not have focus, the shortcut will be inactive. On desktop Chrome, Commands can instead have global scope, as of version 35, and will then also work while Chrome does *not* have focus. NOTE: The exception here is Chrome OS, where global commands are not allowed at the moment.
>
> The user is free to designate any shortcut as global using the UI in chrome://extensions \ Keyboard Shortcuts, but **the extension developer is limited to specifying only Ctrl+Shift+[0..9] as global shortcuts**. This is to minimize the risk of overriding shortcuts in other applications since if, for example, Alt+P were to be allowed as global, the printing shortcut might not work in other applications.

Documentation is available [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands#scope).

Comment: Using the [sample api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:commands) then adding `"global": true` to the toggle-feature command does not work. Works while Chrome is focused. Using Ctrl+Shift+5 as the key

Comment: @Jordan The main gotcha is that changes to keybindings are NOT applied on extension update. Fully uninstall and reinstall the extension for this to take effect. Also: you can go to `chrome://extensions/configureCommands` and manually reassign scope.

Comment: Yes that worked! I guess i'll have to live with this solution. Some keyboards have skip and pause/play buttons, which was the main goal of my question. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: You can use media keys (see the documentation) but you won't be able to assign them as global by default, you'll need to manually adjust scope in the settings.

Comment: do you think I could re-direct the keyboard shortcut with a 3rd party program? So when I press the play/pause key it'll re-direct the shortcut to Ctrl+Shift+1 and the extension will catch the event? --- never mind this, didnt see your second comment